# limit of sequence using squeeze theorm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} {1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\cdot\cdot(2n-1)\over 2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdot\cdot(2n)}$$

I see this should be $0$, and I know I should use the squeeze theorem but I dont see a sequence that is greater and approcahes to $0$.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know something about infinite series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is equivalent to
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\cdot\cdot(2n-1)\over 2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdot\cdot(2n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} {(2n)!\over 4^n(n!)^2}$$
For large $n$ we can use Stirling's approximation $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ on the factorials, resulting (after some cancellation) in
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {(2n)!\over 4^n(n!)^2}\approx\frac{\sqrt{2\pi(2n)}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{4^n(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n)^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}\rightarrow 0$$

Comment: how is it equivalent? how did you get it?

Comment: I have added an intermediate step in the last equation, where I replaced factorial terms $2n!$ and $n!$ by their Striling approximation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: okay got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

One does not need Stirling's approximation to prove this limit. A simple squeeze is sufficient. We will prove the following claim by Mathematical Induction:
\begin{equation*}
\forall\mkern+1mu n \in \mathbb{N} \qquad \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}.
\end{equation*}
The claim clearly holds for $n=1$. Next notice that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
(2 + n) (1 + 2 n)^2 = 2 + 9 n + 12 n^2 + 4 n^3 < 4 + 12 n + 12 n^2 + 4 n^3 = 4 (1 + n)^3.
\end{equation*}
Therefore
\begin{equation} \label{eq1} \tag{*}
\forall\mkern+1mu n \in \mathbb{N} \quad  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \frac{2n+1}{2n + 2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}. 
\end{equation}
Assume that the claim is true for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. That is assume
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}. 
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \frac{2n+1}{2n + 2}.  
\end{equation*}
Now \eqref{eq1} yields
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}.   
\end{equation*}
That is the claim holds for $n+1$. Thus
\begin{equation*}
\forall\mkern+1mu n \in \mathbb{N} \qquad 0 \lt  \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}.
\end{equation*}
By the Squeeze Theorem
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = 0.
\end{equation*}